# почему @media-запрос так себя ведет?

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Почему при вот таком вот коде:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px){
  body{
        background-color: black;
      }
}
```

Если поставить вместо 1000px число > 1000px, всё работает. Как только число < 1000 перестает работать вообще. В чем причина?

Вот сам проект: https://github.com/avoska/transformers

Comment: Масштаб в браузере не 100%. Ctrl+колесо.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o1iMwKR.png я поставил max-width: 800, не работает : (

Comment: ну а вы уверены что за все этим видно хоть кусочек фона body?

Comment: Вот результат при 1500 http://i.imgur.com/3wrD2Zv.png

Comment: ну если уверены, значит добавьте ваш код в вопрос или на худой конец ссылку на проект, чтобы было с чем работать, а то мы же не телепаты, правда?

Comment: https://github.com/avoska/transformers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы работать с `@media` вам необходимо в `head` подключить:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Используйте `only screen` вместо `all`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  //some active
}
```

***Пример***:

```css
.someClass {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .someClass {
     background-color: orange;
   }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="someClass">

  </div>
</body>
```